After Upgrading flutter and alice package to the latest version I was getting these errors
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/alice-1.0.0-dev.10/lib/ui/calls_list/page/alice_calls_list_page.dart:270:63: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
OperatingSystem.isAndroid ? OpenFilex.open(result.path) : null,
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/alice-1.0.0-dev.10/lib/model/alice_export_result.dart:5:17: Context: 'path' refers to a public property so it couldn't be promoted.
final String? path;
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/alice-1.0.0-dev.10/lib/model/alice_export_result.dart:5:17: Context: 'path' couldn't be promoted because field promotion is only available in Dart 3.2 and above.
final String? path;
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/saikumar/Documents/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2663184aa7 (8 days ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
• Engine revision 36335019a8
• Dart version 3.5.3
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/saikumar/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15F31d
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.96.0
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
• sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile)     • emulator-5554         • android-arm64  • Android 15 (API 35) (emulator)
• macOS (desktop)                 • macos                 • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
• Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad • darwin         • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                    • chrome                • web-javascript • Google Chrome 129.0.6668.58
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
I tried these
-- flutter pub cache clean
-- flutter channel stable
-- flutter pub get

What's your dart version? Seems like you are running an old dart version. Context: 'path' couldn't be promoted because field promotion is only available in Dart 3.2 and above

Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2663184aa7 (8 days ago) • 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
Engine • revision 36335019a8
Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3

This is a dev release: "alice-1.0.0-dev.10".  Have you tried rolling back to the latest stable release?

Thank you! Rolling back to the stable version worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help! :)
